# The verb promise

Tags: grammar, verbs

I wanted to know if the following sentences are correct:

Promise me to hand in your paper on time.
Promise me you'll hand in your paper on time.

Answer (score 1):

The second one is fine.

I'm not sure if the first one is actually incorrect, but it certainly sounds clumsy. I think if you're using the infinitive, you wouldn't want the "me". This would work:

> Promise to hand in your paper on time.

Comment: Thanks. I knew there was something wrong with the first one, but couldn't figure it out.